# Log4j: rotate the log file even if the file has not changed

Tags: logging, log4j, rotation

i am trying to rotate the log file everyday by using the DailyRollingFileAppender, but i have a problem: the log files are not updated everyday, so it doesn't get rotate when there is no new stuff in it.

is there a way in the log4j.properties that i can set it so that log4j rotate the log file everyday even if the file has no changes?

Comment: I suspect not; something will need to log so that log4net can actually run code and realise it needs to rotate it (otherwise you'd need a background process). Could you log a single event each day? That should do what you need. What exact problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: i have some other script that tries to grab the log on a daily basis. if the log doesn't get rotate every day, i will be grabbing the same log for more than 1 day, since there's no update in the log, i'm basically grabbing the same log. obviously there are other ways to get around this, but i just want to find out is there a way to do it in log4j.

thanks for your fast reply btw. :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Log4j `DailyRollingFileAppender` will not output an empty file if no logging has occurred. From the [implementation](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/logging/log4j/trunk/src/main/java/org/apache/log4j/DailyRollingFileAppender.java?view=markup):

```
/**
* This method differentiates DailyRollingFileAppender from its
* super class.
*
* <p>Before actually logging, this method will check whether it is
* time to do a rollover. If it is, it will schedule the next
* rollover time and then rollover.
* */
protected void subAppend(LoggingEvent event) {
```